# Как правильно писать message_handler в aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Встретил на просторах интернета такой кусок кода

```
@dp.message_handler(text = 'Отзыв')
async def categories(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, text = ' Отзывы скоро будут', reply_markup = back_kb)

@dp.message_handler(text = 'Назад')
async def categories(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, text='Ты вернулся в главное меню.', reply_markup = start_kb)
```

Допустима ли такая запись?

```
async def msg_handler(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Отзыв':
        await bot.send_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, text = ' Отзывы скоро будут', reply_markup = back_kb)
    elif message.text == 'Назад':
        await bot.send_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, text='Ты вернулся в главное меню.', reply_markup = start_kb)
   else:
        # Типа нет такой команды
```

Если нет, то какие проблемы это может вызвать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не недопустимо, но зависит от того для чего вам такая запись.
Если у вас есть общий код для обоих команд, то впринципе почему бы и нет, в ином случае - такое себе. И читается хуже и архитектура кривая.
По нормальному стоит разбивать на хендлеры, это хорошая практика.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, недопустимо так как это две разные команды.

Каждая команда должна обрабатываться в отдельном хендлере.

Проблемы будут когда нужно будет вывести те же отзывы или перейти в главное меню